# Cakephp v3.0.5 use different model in Component Auth

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I read all the cakephp component Auth documentation in http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html but I cant find a solution :-(

I'm trying to use different model called "Usuarios" in component Auth and change the field "username" by "cedula". This is my configuration in AppController.php:

```
public function initialize() {

        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth');


        $this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
            'Basic' => [
                'userModel' => 'Usuarios', 
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'cedula', 
                    'password' => 'password']],
            'Form' => ['userModel' => 'Usuarios', 
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'cedula', 
                    'password' => 'password']]
]);
```

But nothing happend. No appear login form and session is open.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a login.ctp in src/Templates/Users, and a login() method in your UsersController?

Comment: No, mi login is in src/Templates/Usuarios and in UsuariosController a login() method. I want to use it there and not in Users. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Match the controller name to the template directory, and the method to the template.

If your controller is src/Controllers/Usuarios, method login(), then in src/Templates/Usuarios/ you need to have login.ctp as your view file.

If you have all that, it should work.  By the way, if you are using 'password' as your password field, you don't need to specify that when you configure Auth;  You only need to set 'username' => 'cedula' because you are changing the default.

Also, have you set anything in $this->Auth->allow() in the beforeFilter() method?

Comment: Thank you DJ Far. I have the method login in src/Controllers/Usuarios and login.ctp in src/Templates/Usuarios/. The problem is "Error: UsersController could not be found". dont go to UsuariosController :-(

Comment: In your src/Model/Table, is your table called UsuariosTable, or UsersTable?

Comment: Try typing 'Usuarios/login' in your browser.

Comment: Error: UsersController could not be found. :-(

Comment: Since Users is special to Auth, if I were you I would just use the Users name for Model, View, Controller. Then set the table to 'usuarios' in UsersTable::initialize() $this->table('usuarios');  If you really want to show Usuarios in your URL, set it in your config/routes.php file.